# Internal Server Error 500 in Google App Engine (that gets fixed temporarily by re-deploying)

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, internal-server-error, http-error

I was making this app where it gets data from Google Spreadsheet using a library called gspread. 
This is the code (in python) I used to get data from my Spreadsheet :

```
json_key = json.load(open('service.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
self.gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
self.sheet = self.gc.open('Order Database').sheet1
self.menuSheet = self.gc.open('Menu and Stocking').sheet1
return self.menuSheet.get_all_values()
```

At the beginning the code was working fine, I was using OAuth 2.0 client IDs.
Later when I was working with my android app, to get the data from the website on that url, I started getting Internal Server 500 error, and I can access to that url even from chrome where other part of my website works fine. While searching for solution, I found some people saying to use a API Keys, so I created a server key and even used that, this is the android  code :

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request =new HttpGet(url);
request.addHeader("x-api-key",apikey);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
BufferReader rd = new BufferReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
String line = rd.readLine();
```

The code works fine, at least thats what I think. Every time I get the Internal Server Error 500, if I deploy it again, it starts working fine, but only for a while, soon it starts showing the same error. Looking through the Dashboard of my project I found some detail of the error so I will also include that here :

```
HTTPError: 401: <HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> <H1>Unauthorized</H1> <H2>Error 401</H2> </BODY> </HTML>
at request (/base/data/home/apps/s~gowcanteen/1.394247265273324301/lib/gspread/httpsession.py:75)
at get (/base/data/home/apps/s~gowcanteen/1.394247265273324301/lib/gspread/httpsession.py:79)
at get_cells_feed (/base/data/home/apps/s~gowcanteen/1.394247265273324301/lib/gspread/client.py:250)
at getMenuItems (/base/data/home/apps/s~gowcanteen/1.394247265273324301/server.py:24)
at API_MENU (/base/data/home/apps/s~gowcanteen/1.394247265273324301/main.py:61)
at dispatch_request (/base/data/home/apps/s~gowcanteen/1.394247265273324301/lib/flask/app.py:1461)
at full_dispatch_request (/base/data/home/apps/s~gowcanteen/1.394247265273324301/lib/flask/app.py:1475)
at handle_user_exception (/base/data/home/apps/s~gowcanteen/1.394247265273324301/lib/flask/app.py:1381)
at full_dispatch_request (/base/data/home/apps/s~gowcanteen/1.394247265273324301/lib/flask/app.py:1477)
at wsgi_app (/base/data/home/apps/s~gowcanteen/1.394247265273324301/lib/flask/app.py:1817)
```

I am new to developing and have very little knowledge about OAuths and Credentials, so there might be issues that I do not know and thats why unable to find the problem and fix it. I have added everything that I could think of that could have been related to this issue, so please I ask for your help.

**Some of you may tell this question as duplicate and I know there were others who had similar problems. I checked those, it may be because of my lack of knowledge but I couldn't solve my problem with those. I would have thought of it as a problem in code but then why does deploying it again fixes the problem? And there were some that suggested to use API Key or credentials which I did, so if I have applied it in a wrong way, please correct me. Sorry for making this question too long.**

Comment: Can;t tell from the code you have included how you have structured your program. My guess is the auth session is expiring and you aren't handling any form of re-auth.  If you get 500 error it means you have errors occurring that are not being handled.

Comment: the auth session meaning the day I created the oauth client id right? it hasnt even been a year since then, and i didnt see if there was any date for expiring. now that is the problem that I dont know which part is it thats causing error?  @TimHoffman